# Need Clarification on Facebook Platform Policy with Regards to Storing Graph Data

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Our iOS app allows users to store information about their immediate relatives: name, picture, contact info, birthdate, etc. We want to allow users who login with Facebook to populate that information automatically from the Graph API as an alternative to entering it manually. However, it's not clear to me whether this is allowed by the FacebookSDK terms of service. Specifically, clause 3.14 of the platform policy:

> If you use friend data from Facebook to establish social connections in your app, only do so if each person in that connection has granted you access to that information.

I'm not clear on what it means to "establish social connections" in this context. Am I allowed to store social graph data about the user's family members, either locally or remotely?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Facebook policies; Ask them

Comment: You can only get information about the current user. You can not get name, picture, contact info or birthday from their friends if their friends are not using the app

Comment: If this post is off-topic, how do I contact Facebook about developer policies?  Every reference I could find to contacting Facebook Developer Relations directed me to facebook.stackoverflow.com.